# Replacing While loop with Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, replace, while-loop

I have following SQL statements in SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @Interval table(StartInterval DATETIME,
            EndInterval   DATETIME ) 


        WHILE (DATEADD(mi,1440,@STARTDATE) <= @ENDDATE)
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @Interval
            SELECT @STARTDATE, DATEADD(mi,1440,@STARTDATE)

          SET @STARTDATE = DATEADD(mi,1440,@STARTDATE)
        END
```

@StartDate and @EndDate are two parameters. I am populating a table variable using a while loop and use this table variable further in my stored procedure to join with other tables. But I want to avoid temp table or a table variable. Is there any way I could get the same result (achieved with while loop) with a select query without any iterations or loops? so I could do something like

```
Select * from (logic that replace while loop) Result inner join some table on col1=col2
```

Desired result

```
 StartInterval          EndInterval
2013-10-25 00:00:00.000 2013-10-26 00:00:00.000
2013-10-26 00:00:00.000 2013-10-27 00:00:00.000
2013-10-27 00:00:00.000 2013-10-28 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Look at a recursive CTE. You might find some performance benefits using this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try using CTE:

```
declare @StartInterval datetime, @EndInterval   datetime
select @StartInterval='01-June-2013', @EndInterval   =GETDATE();

with T as (
    select 
        @StartInterval as StartInterval, 
        DATEADD(mi, 1440, @StartInterval) EndInterval
    union all
    SELECT 
        EndInterval, DATEADD(mi,1440,EndInterval)
    FROM T
    WHERE 
        EndInterval <= @EndInterval
)select * from T
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0);
```

OR

```
select StartInterval, DATEADD(mi, 1440, StartInterval) EndInterval
from(
    select DATEADD(mi, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OBJECT_ID)-1)*1440, @StartInterval) StartInterval
    FROM master.sys.all_columns 
)x where StartInterval <=@EndInterval
```

Comment: :Great. how can i join this result with some other table? like Select * from table1,(result from CTE)

Comment: You can treat it as table and use in join
`select * from T INNER JOIN T1 on T.Col=T1.Col`